# Request: Dark Theme

Tags: feature-request

Would it be possible to provide an optional [Dark Theme](https://www.turnoffthelights.com/support/browser-extension/how-to-enable-the-stack-overflow-dark-mode-with-3-easy-steps/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20the%20StackOverflow%20Dark,for%20the%20Stack%20Exchange%20network.) for this site?

To pre-empt a possible recommendation for using extensions, I have tried many of these and they all have had one of two problems:

- They simply don't work very well, often leaving vital elements invisible.
- They contain unwanted script such as google ad injection. Even if you can recommend one that doesn't *now*, it likely will in future, which I've seen happen several times, including ones recommended by Google themselves in their Accessibility pages and settings!

I would also prefer not to run any [custom css injections by random users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284737/dark-theme-for-stack-exchange-sites).

For me, the main thing is the parts where there is a large amount of text should ideally be light-grey text on dark grey background (I am not requesting high-contrast, that would not solve it for me, although that would be another good option in addition to this request for users that need it), to make it easier on the eye. So, not every possible element needs to "go dark", if it is just a side bar or a button.

Comment: This would be better asked on the main Meta Stack Exchange site, since such a feature would presumably be added to not only Mi Yodeya but also her sister sites. And… [it has been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111399)!

Comment: @msh210 yes it seems from that that each site has to do it themselves. I'll read it again

Comment: @msh210 Yes, I have had a look, it seems that each site is responsible for their own style sheet. If SE ever did have any plans to roll out their own global style sheet to all sites (not even sure how that would work?), they clearly abandoned that over a year ago. This is just a request, you are welcome to say no. It's work on your end, but I do hope you say yes :)